In Gerrit's REST API, how do I find the patchset ID Values? I have the url.../details JSON but can't find it in there
I am making a request.get to get the JSON, and want to do it again with the latest patchset and the extension /revisions/(patchSetNumber)/files to find all the modified files. I can't figure out how to find the patchset IDs through the requests.
I have tried searching through the url/details extension but have not been able to locate a revisions tab or a patchset tab.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

According to the documentation, you can specify the ALL_REVISIONS option to get a list of all the revisions associated with a change, e.g for this change, we can get a list of revisions like this (the tail -c+5 is there because of a buggy REST response):
curl -s  'https://review.opendev.org/changes/918316?o=ALL_REVISIONS' |
  tail -c+5 |
  jq -r '.revisions|keys'

This produces:
[
  "14e0f2b73995510d7bd2b0eb84f3b71b92203c78",
  "1bb00656eed24ca7de9f35868910d3c301d8114a",
  "85cebfa4775da4cff725e017e29d2bcba6691642",
  "8831400ebcfe6cfb64526ce92830f574eb826f5e",
  "9d9b03b71a4a0e87321881e5a562d995ae5cf0d9",
  "a0c5cf5ff7a2e18524bc68a10fe82b811d56868e",
  "bd657d0b31152ed3fd2b147bfb1b6e2b0a279bac",
  "cab2417cd4d4f0f7595a1d843dfb44c0410b3a75",
  "d4e653fb2b1ff54298a1262dfc397cc29e845985",
  "d75f457e0e68fbd6a31bca76143264b623ff73bf",
  "f16f39564f2c55584c4ff28abc0d4b48d796c508"
]

We can use those revision ids to get details about each patchset:
$ curl -s  'https://review.opendev.org/changes/918316/revisions/14e0f2b73995510d7bd2b0eb84f3b71b92203c78/files' |
  tail -c+5 |
  jq

Which gets us:
{
  "/COMMIT_MSG": {
    "status": "A",
    "lines_inserted": 12,
    "size_delta": 483,
    "size": 483
  },
  "cinder/db/migrations/versions/a8189e5afd9a_add_volume_type_metadata_table.py": {
    "status": "A",
    "new_mode": 33188,
    "lines_inserted": 53,
    "size_delta": 1601,
    "size": 1601
  },
  "cinder/db/sqlalchemy/models.py": {
    "old_mode": 33188,
    "new_mode": 33188,
    "lines_inserted": 27,
    "size_delta": 784,
    "size": 41911
  },
  "cinder/tests/unit/db/test_migrations.py": {
    "old_mode": 33188,
    "new_mode": 33188,
    "lines_inserted": 5,
    "size_delta": 224,
    "size": 19916
  }
}

In Python, that would look like:
>>> res=requests.get('https://review.opendev.org/changes/918316/revisions/14e0f2b73995510d7bd2b0eb84f3b71b92203c78/files')
>>> data=json.loads(res.text[5:])
>>> list(data.keys())
['/COMMIT_MSG',
 'cinder/db/migrations/versions/a8189e5afd9a_add_volume_type_metadata_table.py',
 'cinder/db/sqlalchemy/models.py',
 'cinder/tests/unit/db/test_migrations.py']

